# How to iterate properly across a const set?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

I'm working on a program that's supposed to represent a graph. My issue is in my printAdjacencyList function. Basically, I have a Graph ADT that has a member variable "nodes", which is a map of the nodes of that graph. Each Node has a set of Edge* to the edges it is connected to. I'm trying to iterate across each node in the graph and each edge of a node.

```
void MyGraph::printAdjacencyList() {
std::map<std::string, MyNode*>::iterator mit;
std::set<MyEdge*>::iterator sit;

for (mit = nodes.begin(); mit != nodes.end(); mit++ ) {
    std::cout << mit->first << ": {";
    const std::set<MyEdge*> edges = mit->second->getEdges();
    for (sit = edges.begin(); sit != edges.end(); sit++) {
        std::pair<MyNode*, MyNode*> edgeNodes = *sit->getEndpoints();
    }
}
std::cout << " }" << std::endl;
}
```

getEdges is declared as:

```
const std::set<MyEdge*>& getEdges() { return edges; };
```

and get Endpoints is declared as:

```
const std::pair<MyNode*, MyNode*>& getEndpoints() { return nodes; };
```

The compiler error I'm getting is:

```
MyGraph.cpp:63: error: request for member `getEndpoints' in 
`*(&sit)->std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator->
[with _Tp = MyEdge*]()', which is of non-class type `MyEdge* const'

MyGraph.cpp:63: warning: unused variable 'edgeNodes'
```

I have figured out that this probably means I'm misusing const somewhere, but I can't figure out where for the life of me. Any information would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are doing this project for homework or for fun, I would suggest you just use the boost library graph representation.

Comment: Yeah, this is homework for a class, so no boost niceness =(

Comment: @Jared good luck with that, then :)
also, you can consider tagging these kind of question with the 'homework' tag, so people will know.

Comment: @Jared @Amir not to worry. If you don't use the BGL you can be grateful for avoiding a lot of headache. Moving from your own mocked graph functionality to the BGL is like moving from `stdio.h` to `iostream`. You'll probably be grateful for that one day, but until then the number of cursewords coming out of your mouth will not put an English football fan to shame.

Comment: You stated that `nodes` is a map, however in `getEndpoints` you return it as an `std::pair`. How is this right?

Comment: @Amir: nodes is a map member of my Graph class, which is where the function I posted is defined. There is also a nodes member variable of my Edge class (contains the endpoint nodes of the edge object), which is where getEndpoints is defined, and that nodes is a Pair. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing `sit` to a `const_iterator`. Change `mit` to a `const_iterator` too while you're at it. Also, `getEdges()` and `getEndpoints()` should be [const functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10). Lastly, because `operator->()` has a higher precedence than the unary `operator*()`, you probably want to say `edgeNodes = (*sit)->getEndPoints()` inside the inner-loop.

Not as much of a problem but you should consider having the iterator instances as local to the loops.

Comment: I've changed both iterators to const_iterators and redefined getEdges and getEndpoints to const functions, no change in compiler error.

Comment: @Jared I updated the answer. I think these changes should calm down the compiler.

Comment: If you still get these errors after these, what happens if you change the return types of those accessors to a return-by-value, instead of return by const-reference?

Comment: That last comment was before the (*sit)->getEndpoints() suggestion. That solved my problem right up, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell anything definite without something compilable, but

```
const std::set<MyEdge*>& getEdges() { return edges; };
```

and

```
const std::pair<MyNode*, MyNode*>& getEndpoints() { return nodes; };
```

should technically be const methods since they don't modify the class and return a const reference.

```
const std::set<MyEdge*>& getEdges() const { return edges; };
const std::pair<MyNode*, MyNode*>& getEndpoints() const { return nodes; };
```

This in combination with `const_iterator` might solve your constness problems.

---

However, your particular error might be that `*it->foo()` `= *(it->foo())`is different from `(*it)->foo()`

Comment: (*it)->foo() did the trick! What exactly do the parens do? Just tell the compiler to treat the dereferenced iterator as an object?

Comment: They change the precedence.  The -> operator has more precedence than the * operator, so it is evaluated first. But you need the * to be evaluated first, so you enclose it with the operand inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

`s/std::set<MyEdge*>::iterator sit;/std::set<MyEdge*>::const_iterator sit;/`

and ditto for mit. In other words, `const_iterator` is what you need here.

Comment: I've changed both iterators to const_iterator and the error is exactly the same.